# Copy stderr and stdout to a file as well as the screen in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh, io-redirection

I'm looking for a solution (similar to the bash code below) to copy both stdout and stderr to a file in addition to the screen within ksh on Solaris.

The following code works great in the bash shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Clear the logfile
>logfile.txt

# Redirect all script output to a logfile as well as their normal locations
exec >  >(tee -a logfile.txt)
exec 2> >(tee -a logfile.txt >&2)
date
ls -l /non-existent/path
```

For some reason this is throwing a syntax error on Solaris.  I assume it's because I can't do process substitution, and I've seen some posts suggesting the use of `mkfifo`, but I've yet to come up with a working solution.

Does anyone know of a way that all output can be redirected to a file in addition to the default locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of ksh are you using?  The `>()` is not supported in ksh88, but is supported in ksh93 - the bash code should work unchanged (aside from the `#!` line) on ksh93.

If you are stuck with ksh88 (poor thing!) then you can emulate the bash/ksh93 behaviour using a named pipe:

```
#!/bin/ksh 
# Clear the logfile  
>logfile.txt  

pipe1="/tmp/mypipe1.$$"
pipe2="/tmp/mypipe2.$$"
trap 'rm "$pipe1" "$pipe2"' EXIT
mkfifo "$pipe1"
mkfifo "$pipe2"
tee -a logfile.txt < "$pipe1" &
tee -a logfile.txt >&2 < "$pipe2" &

# Redirect all script output to a logfile as well as their normal locations  
exec >"$pipe1"
exec 2>"$pipe2"

date   
ls -l /non-existent/path
```

The above is a second version to enable stderr to be redirected to a different file.

Comment: this is almost what I need, but this doesn't keep the STDOUT and STDERR file descriptors separate.  If I invoke the script like `./script.sh >out.log 2>err.log` then all the output goes to out.log, but some should go to the err.log

Comment: ksh in Solaris 10 does support process substitution, but apparently it doesn't work for `exec`

Comment: I guess the tee processes runs forever. May be we need a cleanup code, kill %tee to be done twice.

Comment: @shuva     `tee` exits when it gets EOF (End-Of-File) from its `stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
(some commands ...) 2>&1 | tee logfile.txt
```

Add `-a` to the `tee` command line for subsequent invocations to append rather than overwrite.

Comment: I don't want to have to do this for every command, ideally, I'd like something I can put at the top of the script like in the example above.

Comment: I should also mention that it must be done inside the script.  I have a daemon running the script that captures all output to a logfile, so I don't have control over the invocation on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

In ksh, the following works very well for me

```
LOG=log_file.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).txt
{
ls
date
... whatever command
} 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG
```