# How do I capture STDOUT to a file and STERR and STDIN to a different log file?

Tags: pipe, stdin, ksh, io-redirection, fifo

I'm looking for a solution in ksh93 that will let me run a command and capture the STDERR and STDIN streams to a log file. I also want STDIN and STDERR to output to the terminal. Optionally, in some cases, I would like to capture STDIN to a log file as well (but separate from STDERR).

I have a partial solution, derived from [Copy stderr and stdout to a file as well as the screen in ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075527/copy-stderr-and-stdout-to-a-file-as-well-as-the-screen-in-ksh). I added the code for the 3rd named pipe, which is where I'm having the problem.

```
#!/bin/ksh 
pipe1="/tmp/mypipe1.$$"
pipe2="/tmp/mypipe2.$$"
pipe3="/tmp/mypipe3.$$"

trap 'rm "$pipe1" "$pipe2"' EXIT

mkfifo "$pipe1"
mkfifo "$pipe2"
mkfifo "$pipe3"
tee -a out1.log < "$pipe1" &
tee -a out2.log >&2 < "$pipe2" &
tee -a out2.log < "$pipe3" &      

# Redirect all script output to a logfile as well as their normal locations  
exec >"$pipe1"
exec 2>"$pipe2"
exec "$pipe3"<0      # 0: cannot open [No such file or directory]

unzip $1
```

The above code gives the error `0: cannot open [No such file or directory]` on line 20 (see comment in code).

If I try changing the order of the redirection on line 20 with `exec 0>"$pipe3`, the script seems to operate normally, reflecting all 3 I/O streams to the terminal

```
replace ATO-9500.csv? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
  inflating: ATO-9500.csv
replace ATO-9501.csv? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
  inflating: ATO-9501.csv
replace ATO-9502.csv? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
  inflating: ATO-9502.csv
  inflating: CAPACITOR-9500.csv
  inflating: CAPACITOR-9501.csv
  inflating: CAPACITOR-9502.csv
```

but the output log (out2.log) doesn't contain the user input, and it also merges the STDERR output into a single line:

```
replace ATO-9500.csv? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: replace ATO-9501.csv? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: replace ATO-9502.csv? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

=============

Just to mention, I've tried the process substitution code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe) for capturing STDERR to a log file, and my ksh man pages say that it supports process substitution, but I haven't been able to get it to work for me, so it looks like I'm stuck using the longer approach with named pipes and such.

Comment: could you please show us the script output ?

Comment: Perhaps `script -c "unzip $1" outx.log` helps. You don't have the streams in different files, but it might help for what you want.